# wpf datagrid dynamic bound columns

Tags: wpf, datagrid, binding

Let's assume there is the following class (for example purposes):

```
public class Item
{
    public String Key {get;set;}
    public String[] Values { get; set;}
}
```

for making it simple, imagine the length of each "Item"'s "Values" array is the same.
Let's have a collection of these "Item"s:

ExampleA:

```
List<Item> items = new List<Items>(
    new Item() { Key = "A", Values = new String[]{"OneA", null, "ThreeA"}},
    new Item() { Key = "B", Values = new String[]{"OneB", "TwoB", null}},
    new Item() { Key = "C", Values = new String[]{null, null, "ThreeC"}}
);
```

ExampleB:

```
List<Item> items = new List<Items>(
    new Item() { Key = "1", Values = new String[]{"One1", null}},
    new Item() { Key = "2", Values = new String[]{"One2", "Two2"}},
    new Item() { Key = "3", Values = new String[]{null, null}}
);
```

So how could I make a `DataGrid` from the ToolKit having the following columsn in the next cases:

ExampleA:

```
 A | OneA | ____ | ThreeA |

 B | OneB | TwoB | ______ |

 C | ____ | ____ | ThreeC |
```

ExampleB:

```
 1 | OneA | ____ |

 2 | OneB | TwoB |

 3 | ____ | ____ |
```

So, in words: in different cases the Values arrays have different length. But for one case all the Values arrays have the same length (for simplification).

If `DataGridInstance.ItemsSource` is bound to items (`NotifyPropertyChanged` is implemented), how would the columns are set and how would the binding of the column values are set?

Of course at every refresh `DataGridInstance.Columns.Clear()` is said.
Than the columns are added again, the amount of them is well known (depends on the length of the "Values" array of course).

But how I would create the binding of the values?

I'd like to have something like the following:

```
Binding columnABinding = new Binding("Values[0]");
Binding columnBBinding = new Binding("Values[1]");
Binding columnCBinding = new Binding("Values[3]");
```

Uh, sorry for my bad english. I tried to keep it simple, hope it is understandable!
Thank you for your answers in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582226/how-can-i-display-array-elements-in-a-wpf-datagrid) asked recently, based on my answer over there i doubt that you can bind the columns itself. To refresh the columns you could subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event of one of the items and if the length of the array changes you could rebuild the columns. If the DataContext changes and new items are comming in that way you might also want to handle the `DataContextChanged` event to refresh.